# Find table by column header using xpath

Tags: xpath

[image]

I have the HTML in the screenshot, I can get the table using:

```
//table[contains('@class','table')]
```

but there are several similar tables on the page. Now I want to make sure I have the right table by checking that its ths have a specific column header ( In this case 'Sqft)'.

I tried:

```
//table[contains('@class','table')]//th[contains(text(),'Sqft")
```

but this is failing. How to I get this working?

Comment: `//table[contains('@class','table')]` can not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//table[contains(@class, 'table') and .//th[contains(., 'Sqft')]]
```

or the other way around

```
//th[contains(., 'Sqft')]/ancestor::table[contains(@class, 'table')][1]
```

---

On a general note, in order to prevent partial attribute matches, include the token delimiter in the search. For CSS class names, the delimiter is a space:

```
//table[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' table '))]
```